# Don't know how to build rake db:migrate on Ubuntu natty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, bundler

I'm not sure how to deploy an application using Capistrano but I figured I'd try to at least load all the files I need on my deployment server, so I did a git pull on Github and installed all the dependencies using bundle install. I have RVM 1.6.32 running in Ruby 1.9.2p180 with Rails 3.0.9 and when I run rake db:migrate, I get

`rake aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'`

I don't have the double semi-colon issue that other SO users have mentioned, so I'm genuinely confused. I have rake both 0.9.2 and 0.8.7 installed, as well as bundler 1.0.17. My rvm instance shows 
`rake (0.8.7 ruby)`

What's going wrong?

-- Edit --

The output of rake --tasks

```
rake sunspot:reindex[batch_size,models]  # Reindex all solr models that are...
rake sunspot:solr:run                    # Run the Solr instance in the for...
rake sunspot:solr:start                  # Start the Solr instance
rake sunspot:solr:stop                   # Stop the Solr instance
```

The output of gem list is

```
gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

aaronh-chronic (0.3.9)
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.9)
actionpack (3.0.9)
activemodel (3.0.9)
activerecord (3.0.9)
activeresource (3.0.9)
activesupport (3.0.9)
arel (2.0.10)
authlogic (3.0.3)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.17)
capistrano (2.8.0)
classifier (1.3.3)
daemons (1.1.4)
delayed_job (2.1.4)
docsplit (0.5.2)
erubis (2.6.6)
escape (0.0.4)
fast-stemmer (1.0.0)
gsl (1.14.7)
haml (3.1.2)
highline (1.6.2)
i18n (0.5.0)
lda-ruby (0.3.7)
madeleine (0.7.3)
mail (2.2.19)
mime-types (1.16)
minitest (1.6.0)
mysql (2.8.1)
narray (0.5.9.9)
net-ldap (0.2.2)
net-scp (1.0.4)
net-sftp (2.0.5)
net-ssh (2.1.4)
net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0)
nokogiri (1.5.0)
polyglot (0.3.1)
pr_geohash (1.0.0)
rack (1.2.3)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.9)
rails3-generators (0.17.4)
railties (3.0.9)
rake (0.9.2, 0.8.7)
rdoc (3.6.1, 2.5.8)
rsolr (0.12.1)
shoulda (2.11.3)
thor (0.14.6)
treetop (1.4.9)
tzinfo (0.3.28)
whenever (0.6.8)
will_paginate (3.0.pre4)
```

The output of application.rb is

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
require 'net/http'
require 'net/ldap'
```

Comment: Whats the output of `rake --tasks`?

Comment: place code or command output in your main post, are you in your application directory?

Comment: yes I am in the app directory.

Comment: show your `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 9):

check if `require 'rails/all'` presents in your `config/application.rb` file. Looks like `sunspot` have changed your configs.

also you can try to update your bundler first `gem update bundler`

Comment: `require rails/all` is in application.rb and `gem update bundler` shows everything is updated.

Comment: yes, if you run "rails new app-name -T -O" for example, to have mongodb as a backend DB, but then you want to add mysql too, you'll end up with that issue ...

Comment: Ha ha, yes you just saved me much time.

Answer (score 6):

Try running `bundle exec rake db:migrate` instead. The problem may be that you're not loading in the gems from bundler, and so not getting the tasks defined in those gems (like Rails!).

Comment: It still gave me "Don't know how to build task 'db:migrate'".

Comment: Ok. Can you double-check that you've you run `bundle` to install the gems? What's the output of `gem list`?

Comment: I did run bundle, gem list is as above.

Comment: You've got me stumped, then. Good luck!

Comment: @Rio did you find the solution to this? I am currently stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

I solved with this command

```
bundle install --deployment
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have `Rails.application.load_tasks` in your Rakefile.

If no, add that line.